# ASP.net MVC: How do I define a razor inline template in code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, templates, razor

I'm using razor inline template to define the grid columns format.

[image]

This work great if you are defining the inline template inside a razor view.

**How can I do the same (defining the column list with inline templates) in code in the controller?**

Comment: Why in the Controller?  I still leave the ColumnModels definition in the ViewModel and then emit the grid. Of course, the ViewModel is set by the controller. EDIT: ops, misunderstand the question, sorry. Still low on caffeine today :(

Comment: Eduardo, the MVC pattern is designed and implemented so that only the View knows the details of the user interface, the Controller should not know you are using a grid, grid column, button or whatsoever...

Comment: Davide: I appreciate your concerns. I'm saying the controller and taking the grid as sample for making the question simpler. The solution I'm making is more complex than that. BTW, do you know the answer?

Comment: I think you've over simplified your question.  What you're asking for is definitely a bad practice.  Maybe if you explained what you're really trying to do we could help?

Comment: Kevin: The question is simple :) Do you know the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the sample code. You can also get view code using [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/09/21/viewing-razor-generated-code.aspx). See also [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/09/13/webgrid-helper-with-check-all-checkboxes.aspx) for extending the grid,

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var myClasses = new List<Employee>{
          new Employee   { Name="A" , Price=1, Description="A A"},
          new Employee   { Name="B" , Price=2, Description="B B"},
          new Employee   {  Name="C" , Price=3, Description="C C"}};

        var grid = new WebGrid(source: myClasses);
        var html = grid.GetHtml(
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("Name", "Product", style: "product"),
                grid.Column("Description", format: item => new System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult(writer =>
                {
                    WriteLiteralTo(writer, "<i>");
                    WriteTo(writer, item.Description);
                    WriteLiteralTo(writer, "</i>");
                })),
                grid.Column("Price", format: item => new System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult(wrtier =>
                {
                    WriteLiteralTo(wrtier, "$");
                    WriteTo(wrtier, item.Price);
                }))
            )
        );
        return View();
    }

    private void WriteLiteralTo(TextWriter writer, object content)
    {
        writer.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(content));
    }

    public static void WriteTo(TextWriter writer, object content)
    {
        writer.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(content));
    }

}
```